# Flutter - app localization using intl translations for messages inside Cubit/ Bloc

Tags: flutter, localization

I am working on a multilingual app in Flutter.

I had no problem with implementing the localized strings in widgets/ screens following the official docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization.

But ... my app does a lot of calls to an API which are handled behind the scenes by appropriate Cubits and Repositories. For these calls and other deeper logic I would like to provide status messages in appropriate languages (e.g. for snackbars). The problem I face is that I cannot access localized strings inside the Cubits to provide messages to the state. Even if I try to pass the context to the Cubit it does not see them.

Anyone have an idea please? I would prefer following the official approach and not having to totally refactor the app ...
Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 3):

Somebody helped me with this.
The solution is simple(ish).
You have to pass appLocalizations themselves into the Cubits. Here is my main.dart:

```
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('pl', ''),
      ],
      title: 'MySuperApp',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        accentColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        UserAuthScreen.routeName: (context) => const UserAuthScreen(),
        HomePage.routeName: (context) => HomePage(),
        ...
      }, 
      builder: (context, child) {
        final appLocalizations = AppLocalizations.of(context); //IMPORTANT
        return MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<ConstantsCubit>(
              lazy: true,
              create: (context) => ConstantsCubit(
                constantsRepository: ConstantsRepository(),
              ),
            ),
            BlocProvider<UserAuthCubit>(
              lazy: true,
              create: (context) => UserAuthCubit(
                localizations: appLocalizations, //THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
                repository: UserAuthRepository(),
              ),
            ),
            BlocProvider<DoerInfoCubit>(
                lazy: true,
                create: (context) => DoerInfoCubit(
                      doerInfoRepository: DoerInfoRepository(),
                      userAuthCubit: BlocProvider.of<UserAuthCubit>(context),
                    )),
            ...
          ],
          child: child,
        );
      },
      home:
          BlocBuilder<UserAuthCubit, UserAuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserAuthLogged) {
          return HomePage();
        } else {
          return const UserAuthScreen();
        }
      }),
    ),
  );
```

The UserAuthCubit declaration looks like this:

```
class UserAuthCubit extends Cubit<UserAuthState> {
  final UserAuthRepository repository;
  final AppLocalizations localizations; //THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS

  UserAuthCubit({
    @required this.repository,
    @required this.localizations,
  }) : super(const UserAuthInitial()) {
    getUserAuthState();
  }
```

IMPORTANT - to make sure the solutions works - AppLocalizatons have to be declared **before** the Cubits in the main.dart.
ALSO - the app adopts new localizations in the widgets straight away after language change. However with this setup I was not able to achieve this for Cubits. They need a restart of the app. In real life scenario this should not be a problem ... I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do with the [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package. The only downside is code generation to be done on every string change. Otherwise it doesn't need a context to get a string, like so:

```
LocaleKeys.app_title.tr()
```

Check out the whole [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580) on how to setup and use EasyLocalization.